# Eclipse: Is it Possible to Open Files that are in a Workspace But Not in a Project?

Tags: eclipse

I have a **folder** hierarchy that looks like this:

```
 - workspace
     - some_folder
         + eclipse_project
```

Is it possible to open and view the hierarchy in the project explorer of Eclipse beginning at "some_folder," instead of at "eclipse_project?" If so, how is this accomplished? When I try importing, Eclipse obviously refuses to because the files in the outer folder are already in the workspace.

Or does this contradict the principle behind Eclipse and projects?

Thanks.

Comment: You can drag in eny file into eclipse, and it will open it in an editor. As for a file inside of a project, I think that it can be opened, another matter is that it is not imported, which means it will show it only in file browser, not project browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Or does this contradict the principle behind Eclipse and projects?

Yes, it does. The **File** menu does offer to let you **Open File...**, but whether it's supported by an editor and how much functionality is retained is entirely up to that editor. Some will flat-out fail.

As a workaround, you can create a **New** *General*->*File*, expand the **Advanced** section of the wizard, and set the new in-workspace file to link to the real file's physical on-disk location, **as long as that location is not in some way under the workspace's location**. Note that even this may not always be supported by extremely old editors.

[image]